# python how to refactor opposite number clauses

Tags: python, refactoring

I want to refactor the following two clauses(exact opposite of each other) into one if possible:

```
if who == 0:
    score = take_turn(strategy0(score0, score1), score1, select_dice(score0, score1))
    if score == 0:
        score1 += strategy0(score0, score1)
    else:
        score0 += score
elif who == 1:
    score = take_turn(strategy1(score1, score0), score0, select_dice(score1, score0))
    if score == 0:
        score0 += strategy1(score1, score0)
    else:
        score1 += score
```

How would I make the following possible?

```
def other(who)
    return 1 - who

score = take_turn(strategy+who(score+who, score+other), score+other, select_dice(score+who, score+other))
if score == 0:
    score+other += strategy+who(score+who, score+other)
else:
    score+who += score
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is complex because you scattered data which are related.

So all you have to do is gathering the data and pass it as argument.

There are some possible scenarios and I will use dictionary for following code.

```
dataWho = {"id": 0, "score": score0, "strategy": strategy0}  #gathering related data. function also can be the value of dictionary.
dataOther = {"id": 1, "score": score1, "strategy": strategy1}

def foo(dataWho, dataOther):
    score = take_turn(dataWho["strategy"](dataWho["score"], dateOther["score"]), dataOther["score"], select_dice(dataWho["score"], dateOther["score"]))
    if score == 0:
        dateOther["score"] += dataWho["stratey"](dataWho["score"], dateOther["score"])
    else:
        dataWho["score"] += score
```

I think class implementation is better and you should try it.